# Drupal 7 : jQuery doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I am writing a module for Drupal 7, that has 3 submodules. All submodules have their own module, style and js files. 
In the init function of each submodule I include all javascript files that module uses:

```
  drupal_add_js(path);
```

Everything works fine except jQuery. I tried different ways:

```
  (function ($) {
     alert("1");    
  })(jQuery);

  alert(jQuery('div'));
  alert($('div'));
```

and nothing happening.
Tried to use jQuery as inline function in my module file:

```
  drupal_add_js("(function ($) {alert('1');})(jQuery)","inline");
```

it doesn't work too.

Week before everything worked fine, even popup menus and ajax, based on jQuery. But then I rewrote php functions, add functionality and optimized queries(I haven't modified js files that worked correctly). Maybe I have changed some server configuration files too(I use Denver and run project on localhost).

Only now I realized that my jQuery doesn't work, I have tested everything, spent already 2 days searching for an answer. I know that I made some silly and simple mistake but I can't find where it is. Maybe someone already had such problem, help please.

P.S.: it's my 1-st post here, please don't judge me too harshly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disable js aggregation (if enabled), then check the source code to see if the path to those JS files are correct. If so, I would use Drupal.behaviours around your js as described here http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors If that doesn't work, I would check if there are no js errors popping up somewhere.

Comment: thx for reply, but source code was correct. Now everything works fine, I've reinstalled Drupal. Dunno exactly but maybe the problem was in some other modules or something breaked in core. It looked like jQuery wasn't enabled at all